# why it says I don't have admin privilage to install chatterbot?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, chatterbot

I tried to install chatterbot on my up to date python, pip didn't work, everything including running as administrator and every other thing that I don't remember.

so I went to here:

```
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\
```

with CMD, and did a git clone thing and a chatterbot folder magically appeared. so I did a `pip install -U setuptools` succesfully and tried this: `python setup.py install`

and guess what?

```
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\ChatterBot>python setup.py install
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\config\setupcfg.py:516: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: The license_file parameter is deprecated, use license_files instead.
  warnings.warn(msg, warning_class)
running install
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\setuptools\command\easy_install.py:144: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  warnings.warn(
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\Lib\\site-packages\\test-easy-install-3476.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\site-packages\

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

I am sure that I had run with admin thing. proof:

```
    C:\Users\ali\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\ChatterBot>net user ali
User name                    ali
Full Name
Comment
User's comment
Country/region code          000 (System Default)
Account active               Yes
Account expires              Never

Password last set            2022-11-21 12:48:19 AM
Password expires             Never
Password changeable          2022-11-21 12:48:19 AM
Password required            No
User may change password     Yes

Workstations allowed         All
Logon script
User profile
Home directory
Last logon                   2023-03-06 09:34:35 AM

Logon hours allowed          All

Local Group Memberships      *Administrators
Global Group memberships     *None
The command completed successfully.
```

why doesn't it get fixed automatically with one click or something?

Comment: HOW are you running this as administrator?  Tell us the process you went through.

Comment: right click on CMD and click "run as administrator".

Comment: thanks. how can I get more help? I just wanted to do some trials and errors. can't even get the thing installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.4
```

it's fixed. thanks for help.

Comment: cooool. now i'm trying to upgrade it and getting lot of more errors